# Add a name to pandas dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: data exmple]

As the picture shows , how can I add a name to index in pandas dataframe?And when added it should be like this:
[image: picture]

Answer (score 10):

You need set index name:

```
df.index.name = 'code'
```

Or [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.rename_axis('code')
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=(5,5)),columns=list('ABCDE'),index=list('abcde'))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
a  8  8  3  7  7
b  0  4  2  5  2
c  2  2  1  0  8
d  4  0  9  6  2
e  4  1  5  3  4
```

---

```
df.index.name = 'code'
print (df)
      A  B  C  D  E
code               
a     8  8  3  7  7
b     0  4  2  5  2
c     2  2  1  0  8
d     4  0  9  6  2
e     4  1  5  3  4
```

```
df = df.rename_axis('code')
print (df)

      A  B  C  D  E
code               
a     8  8  3  7  7
b     0  4  2  5  2
c     2  2  1  0  8
d     4  0  9  6  2
e     4  1  5  3  4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's helpful!

Comment: Small advice to future - [don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I got it